Infinitude of Incidence/Order geometry
The incidence axioms state that:

There exist at least three distinct points that are not contained in the same line.
For any two distinct points, there exists one and only one line containing them.
Every line contains at least two distinct points.

The order axioms without Pasch's axiom state that:

If $B$ is between $A$ and $C$, then $A,B,C$ are distinct points on the same line and $B$ is between $C$ and $A$.

For any two points $A$ and $B$, there exists at least one point $C$ such that $B$ is between $A$ and $C$.

Given any three points on the same line, exactly one of them is between the other two.


There are finite geometries that satisfy axioms 1,2,3. Are there any finite geometries that satisfy all 6 axioms above? If Pasch's axiom is added, one can prove that every line has infinitely many points. I suspect that it is a theorem in axioms 1-6 that there exist infinitely many points, but I don't have a proof.

All you need is the existence of one line and two points on it to use 5 and induction to show the existence of infinitely many more points on the line, using 4 to show that the new points must be on the line, and 6 to show that they cannot circle back and "reuse" existing points.

Using the method you describe I can only show there are five distinct points on a given line. I can't get a contradiction with having only 5 points on a line.

Sorry, I was implicitly assuming Hilbert's original axiom II.4 was also true, which was later proved redundant (thus reducing the numbering of Pasch's axiom from II.5 to II.4). But the proof of that former axiom relies on others of Hilbert's axioms not included here.
